# Trying to understand rlang sym(id) error In R

Tags: r

I wonder how I can sort this bug in R.
My simple lines

```
Remit_data <- panel_data(dataremit, id = id, wave = t)

model<-asym(wel_loggdp_cap ~ logremit + remitsq + logcpi + corruption + 
           employilo + senrol_netprim + logfert + urbanization + tradegdp + 
           netoda_gini, data = dataremit)
```

I get this error

> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols Backtrace:
>
> 1. panelr::asym(...)
> 2. panelr:::diff_data(...)
> 3. rlang::sym(id)

Answer (score 1):

In `panelr` you have to define your panel data classifier (e.g. id / time) outside of the `wmb` function. You can compare this to `plm` were it can be done within `plm`.

```
library(panelr)
library(plm)
data(Produc)

# fixed effects with plm
FE_plm <- plm(gsp ~ pcap + pc + pcap:pc,
                data = Produc, 
                index = c("state","year"),
                method="within")

# fixed effects with panelr
Produc <- panel_data(Produc, id = state, wave = year)

FE_panelr <- wbm(gsp ~ pcap + pc + pcap:pc, 
                 model = "within",
                 interaction.style = c("double-demean"),
                 data = Produc)
```

This should fix the issue. Always try to provide a minimal working example.